# Is creating a new object recursively slower than creating a reference?

Tags: java, recursion, instantiation

Say I have the following code:

```
    public static ArrayList<Integer> doSomething(int n) {

    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    if (n <= 0)
        return list ;
    list = ListMethods.doSomething(n - 1);
    list.add(n);

    return list;
```

Is this any slower than this code:

```
    public static ArrayList<Integer> doSomething(int n) {

    ArrayList<Integer> list = null;
    if (n <= 0)
        return list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list = ListMethods.doSomething(n - 1);
    list.add(n);

    return list;
```

I ask because one of my lecturers uses the latter code in his notes, whereas I've seen other guides online use the former. Is it just personal preference, or is there a speed difference? Additionally, if there is a speed difference, is it too small to be concerned with?

Comment: Where is recursion in this code?

Comment: Apologies - didn't post all the code to save space. Should have realised it doesn't make sense without it!

Comment: Using an assignment to a local variable *in a return statement* is pointless. (Well, there are cases where it could matter in finally blocks, but it's pointless here.)

Comment: @JonSkeet: What would you recommend as an alternative? To declare a static list outside the method? (which I would have done but wasn't allowed to!!)

Comment: Creating an object is slower than not creating an object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the first code is slower. For *every* value of `n` greater than 0, you end up with the first part equivalent to:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list = ListMethods.doSomething(n - 1);
```

There's no point in creating a new `ArrayList` object and immediately assigning a different value to the same variable.

The second code is better, but could still be improved significantly in terms of readability:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> doSomething(int n) {
    if (n <= 0) {
        return new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> list = doSomething(n - 1);
    list.add(n);
    return list;
}
```

This only uses a `list` variable if it actually *needs* to. It's pointless to even declare it for the `n <= 0` case, where you're *just* going to return a new `ArrayList<Integer>`.

Comment: So would it be better to create the ArrayList statically, and outside the method, so it doesn't need to be touched until required, or is it better to do it inside the method, set it to null and only instantiate it when the recursion has reached its end statement?

Comment: @AndrewMartin: No, there's no need for the `list` variable as early as you had it. See my edit for better code. Alternatively, you *could* create the list outside the call, and pass it into the method as an argument, changing it to a `void` method. Of course, I'd change this code to avoid being a recursive method at all - I assume your real situation is a bit more complicated.